# How to map ResultObject<RequestList[]> using rxjs?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular14

can someone help understand how to map ResultObject<RequestList[]>? What I tried now doesn't work, I get the following error at line after the first map.

**Property 'data' is missing in type '{ ... }[]' but required in type 'ResultObject<RequestList[]>'**

```
    public getFiltredRequestListt(
    filter: RequestFilter
  ): Observable<ResultObject<RequestList[]>> {
    return this.http
      .get<ResultObject<RequestList[]>>(`${this.apiUrl}...}`
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response: ResultObject<RequestList[]>) => {
          const requestList: ResultObject<RequestList[]> = response.data.map(
            (request: RequestList) => ({
              ...request,
              validFrom: request.validFrom
                ? new Date(request.validFrom!)
                : request.validFrom,
              validUntil: request.validUntil
                ? new Date(request.validUntil!)
                : request.validUntil,
            })
          );
          return requesttList;
        })
      );
  }
```

Here are the different models I'm using:

```
export interface ResultObject<T> {
  data: T;
  resultAction?: ResultAction;
}

export interface ResultAction {
  code: number;
  message: string;
}

export interface RequestList {
  ...
  validFrom: Date;
  validUntil: Date;
}
```

Comment: what it is saying is that your interface for ResultObject expects a property named data. You have not provided this prop.

Comment: the property data contains the array RequestList[] but I didn't found how to map it

Comment: No, you're saying you need ResultObject<RequestList[]> . However, map produces an array. So your map returns an array of RequestList. So what you are saying is ResultObject<RequestList[]> = RequestList[]. You can see this if you break it up into separate variables and look at their types. Since all you're doing is just updating the valid values. Just do response.data = what you have now

Answer (score 1):

As SomeStudent already said, you actually return RequestList[] instead of ResultObject<RequestList[]>.

If you want actuala ResultObject you should do:

```
       public getFiltredRequestListt(
        filter: RequestFilter
      ): Observable<ResultObject<RequestList[]>> {
        return this.http
          .get<ResultObject<RequestList[]>>(`${this.apiUrl}...}`
          )
          .pipe(
            map((response: ResultObject<RequestList[]>) => {
              const requestList: ResultObject<RequestList[]> = new ResultObject<RequestList> {
               data: response.data.map(
                (request: RequestList) => ({
                  ...request,
                  validFrom: request.validFrom
                    ? new Date(request.validFrom!)
                    : request.validFrom,
                  validUntil: request.validUntil
                    ? new Date(request.validUntil!)
                    : request.validUntil,
                })
              ),
               resultAction: response.resultAction
              };
              return requesttList;
            })
          );
      }
```